# get value from json object in html

Tags: html, angular, typescript

How can I show only the value **100** in the div below?

```
<div> {{uploadProgress | async | json}} </div>
```

The current value shown is:

> [ { "filename": "Mailman-Linux.jpg", "progress": 100 } ]

Below my interface from .ts file:

```
interface IUploadProgress {
  filename: string;
  progress: number;
}
```

Comment: What about `<div> {{uploadProgress.progress}} </div>`?

Comment: no, nothing shows when I do that, also progress is not available to uploadProgress in intellisense in the typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `uploadProgress | async`  gets the objects of the stream.

After the AsyncPipe it will probably print out `[Object object]`

Since this is now an object you can simple get the progress attribute like any other object.

Result should look like this:

```
  <div> {{(uploadProgress | async).progress}} </div>
```

Additionaly when the observable you have is not an BehaviourSubject then you might want to add a [safe navigation](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/introduction-to-safe-navigation-operator-in-angular-2/) with `?` after the Asyncpipe to prevent `undefined` errors:

```
  <div> {{(uploadProgress | async)?.progress}} </div>
```

As ShamPooSham correctly mentions, it seems the result is an array. 
Therefore the answer should look like this:

```
   <div> {{(uploadProgress | async)[0]?.progress}} </div>
```

Comment: It seems as the result is an array, so if OP just wants the first value you should add a 0-index

Comment: sorry but {{(uploadProgress | async).progress} with or without the ? still doesn't show anything

Comment: now returns this error:  Parser Error: Conditional expression (uploadProgress | async)?[0].progress requires all 3 expressions at the end of the expression [ {{(uploadProgress | async)?[0].progress}} ]

Comment: DarkW1nter ok my bad the ? should be after the index